# can python xlrd change a column type in an .xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I want to use xlrd to read an set of .xlsx files created by someone else who unfortunately incorrectly formatted a column in Excel. The column is a section label (text) such as 1.2.3.4. but it's formated as a date. It displays OK in Excel, but when I try to read it in using xlrd it is read in as a date. I tried "converters={'Section': str}", but got an error

OverflowError: normalized days too large to fit in a C int

(the cell in question had no entry.)

I have read around a bit, but can't find a good way of fixing the .xlsx file so that the columns have the right datatype.

How do I fix or read the .xlsx file so that I can read the right datatype without errors.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, if a cell is formatted as a date, it's stored as a floating point number.  (See [Dates in Excel Spreadsheets](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html)).

So the original input data is lost.  The only thing stored is the floating point number, which is re-constructed by Excel on load.

You can verify this by printing the cell contents.  If you can't, for some reason (you say this causes an error), you may be able to grab the cell and change it's `ctype` attribute to 1 for text.  For example:

```
cell = sheet.cell(r,c)
print(cell)    # xldate:37623.0  (if this causes an error, comment it out)
cell.ctype = 1
print(cell)    # text:37623.0
```

What you *may* be able to do is tease out the original value by converting the floating point number to a tuple via [`xlrd.xldate_as_tuple`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#xldate.xldate_as_tuple-function)

```
cell = sheet.cell(r,c)
print(cell)
print(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(cell.value, workbook.datemode))
```

Example output:

```
1/2/3                  # Entered in cell
xldate:37623.0         # print(cell)
(2003, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0)  # print(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(...))

1/2/3                  # Entered in cell
xldate:38415.0         # print(cell)
(2003, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0)  # print(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(...))
```

Then you'd operate on the data of the tuple directly, once you figure out the relationship between the tuple elements and the data Excel displays.

If this doesn't work, a trimmed-down minimal example .xls file would be helpful for further diagnosis.

**Note:** This was written using xlrd version 0.9.3.  In the above examples, `workbook` is the variable holding the workbook (e.g. via [`xlrd.open_workbook`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#__init__.open_workbook-function)) and `sheet` is the variable holding the worksheet (e.g. via [`workbook.sheet_by_index`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#__init__.Book.sheet_by_index-method)).

---

**Update:** Per the discussion in comments, you could do something like:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('file.xlsx', ragged_rows=True)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

def safe_cell(cell):
    try:
        str(cell)
    except ValueError:
        cell.ctype = 1
    return cell

def safe_get(sheet, r, c):
    cell = sheet.cell(r,c)
    return safe_cell(cell)
```

And then access the cells with one of the following approaches:

```
# Approach (a)
for r in sheet.nrows:
    for c in sheet.ncols:
        cell = safe_get(sheet, r, c)
        # You can now operate on cell without worrying about it raising a ValueError

# Approach (b)
for r in sheet.nrows:
    for cell in sheet.row(r):
        cell = safe_cell(cell)
        # You can now operate on cell without worrying about it raising a ValueError
```

You *may* be able to do something like:

```
for r in sheet.nrows:
    for cell in sheet.row(r):
        try:
            str(cell)
        except ValueError:
            cell.ctype = 1
```

Once, at the beginning of your script, and it *may* "fix" your cells for when you read them later, but since I can't reproduce your issue, I can't guarantee this.

If this doesn't work, using one of the two approaches (using the `safe_*` functions) will work, but you'll need to use it everywhere you access a cell from the sheet.

Comment: Thanks. I got "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''" at the "print(cell) step. That might work. I can "fix" an individual cell to print with the "right" format. But is there a quick way of correcting all the cells in all the columns in all the sheets in all the workbooks I have to process? I can step through all the cells one-by-one, but there might be a more elegant way.

Comment: @pheon Just to be clear, when you run the steps in the first code block, you get the `ValueError` for the first `print(cell)` but when you change the `ctype`, you're able to access the data?  If that's true, then I've got an idea about how to make sure all the cells that would otherwise error are set to `ctype = 1` before you read from them, and only the ones that would error -- would that work for you?

Comment: Yes. That's right. There are many cells in the set of .xlsx files I am trying to read, that are marked as "date" by Excel which cause an error when I try to read them into pandas using xlrd. Your fix works on a cell-by-cell basis, but what I really need is a general solution which will not cause an error when I read all the files.

Comment: @pheon see my update.  It's possible you could use the code in the bottom block once, after you open your workbook and select your sheet, and then future reads will be fine.  If the bottom approach doesn't work, the two approaches above it *will* work, but you'll need to use the `safe_get` or `safe_cell` functions everywhere you access a worksheet cell.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey @jedwards, great in-depth answer. I am trying a similar thing, xlrd has converted a text column with value "TRUE" to boolean. I tried what you wrote but unfortunately, I am only getting 1 as the content. 
Any way to retrieve the original value? Like you deduced the date in this